# NodeJS Script Runs on Local Machine but Not in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

My script written in NodeJS connects to Firebase, checks my Firebase Database and even successfully sends notifications when results from my database return true...  However, it only works when I run it from my local machine.  I deploy it to Firebase and it will not work.  Could someone please advise?  Thank you.

I hate asking on here because I'm a newbie but I have spent hours tonight trying to find an answer...

INDEX.JS

```
// Firebase Functions
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

// Default admin firebase configuration
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

// var serviceAccount = require("xxxxxx-80xxxxd-firebase-adminsdk-  xxxxxxx.json");
var moment = require('moment');
var FCM = require('fcm-push');
var dateTime = require('node-datetime');

var serverKey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxpSELZBjQYwpZgmxxxxxxxxxxx';
var fcm = new FCM(serverKey);


//Initial function call:
exports.CheckDates = functions.https.onRequest((req, response) => {

// Get a database reference to our posts
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("records");
var userToken = '';
var itemExpires = '';
var itemName = '';
var reminded = '';
var itemCount = 0;
var counter = 1;
var itemFoundCount = 0;
var dt = dateTime.create();
var formatted = dt.format('m-d-Y');

ref.once("value", function (recordsSnapshot) {
recordsSnapshot.forEach(function (recordsSnapshot) {
    var mainKey = recordsSnapshot.key;
    recordsSnapshot.forEach(function (child) {
        var key = child.key;
        var value = child.val();
        if (key == 'Account') {
            userToken = value.userToken;
        }
        if (key == 'Items') {
            recordsSnapshot.child("Items").forEach(function (itemsSnapshot) {
                 counter++;
                if (itemFoundCount === 0) {
                     itemFoundCount = itemsSnapshot.numChildren();
                }
                var itemsChildkey = itemsSnapshot.key;
                var itemsChildvalue = itemsSnapshot.val();
                itemExpires = itemsChildvalue.itemExpires;
                itemName = itemsChildvalue.itemName;
                reminded = itemsChildvalue.reminded;
                moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                var currentDate = moment();
                var otherTime = moment(reminded);
                if (typeof reminded !== 'undefined') {
                    if (currentDate.diff(otherTime, 'days') >= 30) {
                         if (currentDate.diff(itemExpires, 'days') <= 90) {
                            itemCount++;
                            console.log("Expire date is less than " +
      currentDate + " by 90 days = " + (currentDate.diff(otherTime, 'days') <=
     90));
                        db.ref("records/" + mainKey + "/Items/" +
         itemsChildkey + '/reminded').set(formatted);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                itemCount++;
                db.ref("records/" + mainKey + "/Items/" + itemsChildkey +
        `enter code here`'/reminded').set(formatted);
            }
            if (counter == itemFoundCount && itemCount > 0) {
                console.log(itemFoundCount);
                var message = {
                    to: userToken, // required fill with device token or
       topics
                    notification: {
                        title: 'Item Expire Notification',
                        body: itemCount + ' is about to expire.'
                    }
                };
                //callback style
                fcm.send(message, function (err, response) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log("Something has gone wrong!");
                    } else {
                        console.log("Successfully sent with response: ",
        response);
                    }
                });
                itemCount = 0;
                itemFoundCount = 0;
                counter = 1;
            }
        });
    }
});
});
});

 response.send(200, "ok");
})  // END exports.CheckDates
```

Obviously, I remove the Exports.CheckDates lines when I run it locally but it wasn't showing up at all without the exports on Firebase's console.  It returns warnings locally and on Firebase console but it works on one and not the other.

Comment: <snip>I hate asking on here because I'm a newbie</snip>what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please disregard this question.  The script adds the date that the last time a notification was sent to the item's "Reminded" key in the database... this prevents notifications from going out every day for the same thing..

It ran on my local machine, and did it's job but I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't run again...  well, ha!  At least we know that part works.